# Why does listbox consume so much memory when images are aquired from Isolated Storage as opposed to an image embedded in the assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have created a List Box in Windows Phone Mango.

I will be using it to display many photos in one long list.

For testing purposes I am just using one photo and repeating it for each index.

When loading the image from Isolated Storage 100 images consume 170MB of memory.

When I embbed the same image in the assembly as a resource (ie /Images/image1.jpg) 10'000 images only consume 40MB. In fact it never goes above 40MB, whatever is happeing here (UI Virtualization?) it works well.

I have to use Isolated Storage for my images, as image updates are downloaded periodically to the phone. Can I make it perform the same as an embedded image?

Can someone explain to me;

1. When I aquire the image from Isolated Storage, why does it uses so much memory, the more I load the higher it gets?
2. When I aquire it from the images folder, when it is part of the assembly, how can it load tens of thousands of images and the memory never increases, is this UI Virtualization?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Here is my code. (Only started developing 6 months ago if it looks a bit dodgy!)

//GET IMAGE FROM ISOLATED STORAGE

```
IsolatedStorageFile insISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            byte[] byte1;

            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = insISF.OpenFile("\\Photos\\image1.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte1 = new byte[isfs.Length];
                isfs.Read(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
                isfs.Close();
            }

            Image image = new Image();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byte1);
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.SetSource(ms);
            image.Source = bi;
            listBox2.Items.Add(image);
    //NOTE I HAVE TRIED "ms.Dispose();" HERE BUT IT DOES NOT HELP.
        }
```

//END

//GET IMAGE FROM IMAGES FOLDER AS PART OF ASSEMBLY

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/image1.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = bi;            
        listBox2.Items.Add(image);
        }
```

//END

Comment: Please check, is it possible or not to load `BitmapImage` with an `Uri` such as `isostore:/` without manipulating with files

Answer (score 2):

When you load image from `Isolated Storage`, you load it byte-by-byte, e.i. all images are loaded completely.

In opposite, when you create `BitmapImage`, it uses `DelayCreation` option by default. So, application loaded images that only on screen now. See `CreateOption` enum for more details.

[Off-thread decoding of images on Mango](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/13/off-thread-decoding-of-images-on-mango-how-it-impacts-you-application.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That makes sense as the Isolated Storage method takes much, much longer to load. Is there a way to delay image creation when aquiring the images from Isolated Storage?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the IsolatedStorageFileStream and MemoryStream objects???

Try using GC to monitor the memory usage of each iteration in your for loop.

The virtualization on your listbox should work the same in either case.

Btw, you should use the using construct on MemoryStream as well.

Comment: Wow that was a fast reply! I will look into the Garbage Collector now. I am aware of it, but never interacted with it. I will post back any results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the byte array is disposed by the Garbage Collector, the only objects that should be explicitly disposed by the garbage collector once they are out of scope are the one that can be included in a `using` statement...

I never tried, but I think that if you read the images directly from the stream instead of reading it from the stream, writing it to an array and re-reading it from an array, *and* including the stream in a `using` statement the memory should be freed.

Hope this help.